# Flutter Location package generates platform exception on call to serviceEnabled()

Tags: flutter

Flutter 2.0.6, Location package 4.1.1.

This snippet of code...

```
  try {
    _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
  } on PlatformException catch (err) {    
    print ("Platform exception calling serviceEnabled(): $err");
    _serviceEnabled = false; 
  }
```

Generates:  Platform exception calling serviceEnabled(): PlatformException(SERVICE_STATUS_ERROR, Location service status couldn't be determined, null, null)

But here's the interesting part:  this error *only* comes up when I run a release build on my Samsung Galaxy S8.   If I run a debug build on the S8, or if I run either a release or a debug build on an android emulator, no error is thrown.  I've tried a few different emulator configurations, specifically one configured as closely to the S8 -- Android version 9 (SDK 28), and same screen size.

Any suggestions for how to investigate why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
initLocation() async {
    try {
      _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    } on PlatformException catch (err) {
      print("Platform exception calling serviceEnabled(): $err");
      _serviceEnabled = false;

      // location service is still not created

      initLocation(); // re-invoke himself every time the error is catch, so until the location service setup is complete
 }   }
```

call initLocation() from initState()

```
@override void initState() {
super.initState();
initLocation(); }
```

problem is related with some Android timeout processes, so the recursive call

credit-[issue thread](https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/issues/568)